# How to provide customized vibration on specific incoming calls

Tags: android, telephonymanager, vibration, android-audiomanager

The program functions like this: the user has a list of phone numbers, for which the cellphone could vibrate upon an incoming call only when no other system-wide application would provide vibration (such as in mute mode).  I know that this is somehow against the rules, for that an application should respect the users' settings, but the application is limited to some certain users with this need.  I have tried two ways but neither of them are satisfying:

1. Listen to the telephony state and directly trigger the vibration service with my own pattern (with `Vibrator.vibrate()`).  This method is effective with no incoming calls yet randomly effective when the phone is in `CALL_STATE_RINGING` state and I guess it's because of the conflict with the system-wide application that actually handles the vibration upon incoming call.
2. Judge whether the cellphone is vibrating upon an incoming call (with `AudioManager.shouldVibrate()`), and decide whether to change the vibrate settings (with `AudioManager.setRingerMode()` and `AudioManager.setVibrateSetting()`).  If the vibrate settings are changed by my application, they are to be restored once the cellphone is back to `CALL_STATE_IDLE` state.  This method, however, is still not functioning sometimes, without any sign of the reason.

I hope that someone could give some advice on this issue.  Comments on these two ways or other suggest are welcome.

Comment: @Rizon Sadly no, and this question earns me a tumbleweed badge.

Comment: This is not the same but someone tryed disabling vibration on incomming calls and it proved impossible, but the findings are interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8065862/969325

Comment: @Warpzit Thanks.  It seems if I could receive the broadcast before Ringer do, the problem is solved.  I am not sure how to do that, maybe I should check Ringer.java out.

Comment: `setVibrateSetting()` with `setRingerMode()` seems to work on my phone. Could you post your code?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov Well, actually they work for my phone as well.  The problem appears on my friend's device being tested.  I am just looking for some more robust way.  Code is too long and complicated, and I am afraid it's not where the problem lies.

Comment: Hello Peter. I have having same issue. Can you please help me? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to play with two settings in order for your phone to vibrate. The first one is the sound mode which needs to be set by using AufioManager:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(targetSoundMode);
```

The second part is not properly documented and I believe this is the missing part of your code:

```
String VIBRATE_IN_SILENT_SETTING_NAME = "vibrate_in_silent";
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), VIBRATE_IN_SILENT_SETTING_NAME, 1);
```

use 1 to turn vibrate on and 0 to turn vibrate off.

to fully understand how you should work with vibrate settings and mode take a look at the following link:
http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/settings/SoundSettings.java.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this is not what blocks the vibrator, because `vibrate_in_silent` is already set to 1.  Is it possible that Phone.apk cancels the Vibrator immediately after we trigger it?  According to [VibratorService.java](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/VibratorService.java), the Vibrator would behave randomly in this situation.  And this explains why the problem only occurs on some cellphones: Phone.apk is not part of the System.

Comment: Have you looked at the setPhoneVibrateSettingValue function on the link above ? There is some dependency between these two settings that should be handled very carefully

Comment: The dependency is something I've missed.  I am going to perform some tests on more devices for the dependency.  Thanks in advance!  +1 to you.

Comment: Link is dead. I am having same issue. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Prince Hi, you can view [SoundSettings.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.L_preview/com/android/settings/SoundSettings.java) in the latest release code.

Comment: @peter Okey let me check it. Just to know is it possible to set level of vibration at incoming call ? I have asked question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804939/how-to-change-incoming-call-vibration-level-when-incoming-call-made

Comment: @Prince I don't think so as I have never seen docs related to level.

Comment: @peter :( Okey friend. My bad luck.